# function key for password entry

Tags: bash, password

I want to have my password "fed" to bash via a single programmable function key. This will save effort when a script has, for example, multiple invocations of `ssh` and `rsync` and `scp`. I suppose if multiple passwords are remembered then a different function key could be allocated for local host `sudo` but that's not essential because `sudo` is not as inconvenient because Ubuntu does not prompt if the password was entered recently within a timeout period. The priority is for remote hosts.

What is the easiest way to do this? Is there any way easier than writing some sort of wrapper for bash?

Comment: I would use expect scripts, not exactly what you are asking for. http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts

Comment: Instead of trying to reduce your password to a single key stroke, you should consider using ssh keys so that your scripts would not need any password entry and would be safer anyway.

Comment: When it comes to `ssh`, private keys definitely are the way to go, everything else is just unnecessarily unsafe, *especially* storing your password in plain text. If that's not an option how about using a password manager like [`pass`](https://www.passwordstore.org)?

Comment: @muclux, Are you sure keys are safer than passwords when machines can be stolen?